# Using bcp export in xp_cmdshell to export a csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
SELECT @sql = 'bcp database1.dbo.table1 out Z:\test.csv'  + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ '.\SQL2005'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

But I get error saying

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 17 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>   SQLState = 01000, NativeError = 53 Warning = [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). NULL

Comment: Is the Z: drive mapped to the windows account running SQL Server Service?  If not, try using the UNC path instead.

Comment: Yes, it is mapped, and I tried UNC path as well, still doesn't work

Comment: Does that account have permissions to the folder?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I can do bulk insert of csv file from the same folder

Comment: When you do the bulk insert, are you using the same argument for the server name? `-S.\SQL2005`?  Is that comma between the `-t, -T` supposed to be there?

Comment: My bcp insert is in a stored procedure; I just moved export query in a stored procedure as well then it worked! Thank you!